# Text blocks to paragraph combining algorithm... where to start from?

Tags: algorithm, pdf, text, text-extraction, pdf.js

I have a bunch of text pieces extracted from the PDF document or image. Each piece is a short one-row height text string. Each piece has a x, y coordinate and sometimes rotation. I think I also can calculate metric width&height of each piece.

The problem is to concatenate those piece into paragraphs using coords & dimensions and some heuristics.

Trying to find a ready solution for a hour but found nothing (I was sure it was created already!).

When do you recommend me to start digging from?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you can sort the boxes by `x` and `y` values and print the results in order. Have you tried this already?

Answer (score 1):

For regular text, get the left and right (start/end) midpoint for each piece and just match each left bit with the closest right bit with similar orientation within a small radius. This give you sentences. Repeat with top and bottom midpoints to get paragraphs.

For more crazy setup (like handwritten notes, crazy layouts, etc), instead of matching the closest create a closeness estimate function base on distance and angle, and run bipartite graph matching to minimize the cost. Make sure you eliminate pairs that are too far apart or the angle changes too abruptly. Might not work well for paragraphs (not sure what points to consider on a spiral of text).

To make it even better (for both versions) you could train (or copy) a markov chain text model on similar text. The model will tell you how likely are the pairings you are creating. You can factor that into the closeness estimate function to bias the pairing towards sentences that make more sense.